# is there a sophisticated way to grep this file

Tags: grep

I have one file. Written in BNF it could be

```
 <line>:== ((<ISBN10>|<ISBN13>)([a-Z/0-9]*))  {1,4})
```

For example

```
   123456789X/abscd/1234567890123/djfkldsfjj
```

How can I grep the ISBN10 or ISBN13 ONLY one per line even when in the line are more ISBNs. If there are more ISBNs in the line it should take only the first in line.

When I grep that way

```
     grep -Po "[0-9]{9,13}X{0,1}" file
```

then I get more lines than the file originally has. (As there could be max 4 ISBNs in line)

I would also need the linecount of file should be the linecount of the grepresult.

Any advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assuming the other answer offered isn't correct in assuming that the 'first' ISBN isn't at the start of line, you could always try in perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my ( $first_isbn, @rest ) = m/(\d{9,13}X{0,1})/g;
    print $., ":", $first_isbn, "\n" if $first_isbn;
}
```

`$.` is the line number in perl, and so we print that and the match if there's a match. `<>` says read and iterate either filenames or STDIN much like grep does. So you could invoke this in a similar way to grep:

```
perl myscript.pl <filename>
```

Or:

```
cat <filename> | ./myscript.pl
```

This would one-liner-ify as:

```
perl -lne 'my ( $first_isbn ) = m/(\d{9,13}X{0,1})/g; print $., ":", $first_isbn, "\n" if $first_isbn;'
```

Comment: Thanks, yes The First ISBN Need not be at the beginning of the line, but I think the perl solution is correct

Answer (score 0):

One trivial solution is to include the beginning of the line in your regex:

```
grep -Po "^[0-9]{9,13}X{0,1}" file
```

This ensures that matches after the first do not satisfy the regex. It does seem from your BNF that the ISBNs, if present, are guaranteed to be the first characters of the line.

Another way is to use sed:

```
 sed -n "s/\([0-9]\{9,13\}X\).*/\1/p" file
```

This matches your pattern along with the rest of the line, but only prints your pattern. You could then use another utility to add line numbers. E.g. pipe your output to `nl -nrz -w9`.